# My mysql update query isnt working

Tags: php, mysql

for some reason, I can't get this to work.

Thanks in advance, a secnod eye might help!

```
$sql3 = "SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE order_code = '$order_code'";
$result3 = $conn->query($sql3) or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
$order_id = $row['order_id'];       

$deliv_date = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "UPDATE orders SET deliv_date = $deliv_date
                WHERE order_id = $order_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO invoice VALUES (0,'$order_code','$deliv_date','','$order_id')";

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1) or exit("Error code ({$conn->errno}): {$conn->error}");
```

Comment: Try like `$sql = "UPDATE orders SET deliv_date = '$deliv_date'
                WHERE order_id = $order_id";`

Comment: @user3395352: Great. I'm glad that your problem was resolved. It's basically a typo and is not likely to be useful to a future visitor. You can now delete this question, if you want.

Comment: @user3395352, Glad you got it working. Yeah that's correct Amal.

Comment: it didn't let me delete it because answer

Comment: @user3395352, You were pretty late :P

Comment: @user3395352: You should be able to delete it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE `orders` SET `deliv_date` = '".$deliv_date."'
                WHERE `order_id` = '".$order_id."'"
```